# How can I make rails route helpers always use to_param to generate the path, even when I just pass in an ActiveRecord ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, seo, routes, helper

So, I'm implementing a pretty/SEO-friendly URL scheme for my rails app.  I have a model called Artist, and I would like the Rails `artist_path` helper to always generate the friendly version of the path.

In my routes.rb file, I have the following line:

```
  get 'artists/:id(/:slug)', :to => 'artists#show', :as => 'artist'
```

If the slug is left out, or is incorrect (it's calculated by the artist name), the controller 301 redirects to the correct URL.  However, for SEO reasons, I want to ensure that all links internal to my site have the correct URL to start with.

The Artist model has the two following (very simple) functions to allow this to work:

```
  def slug
    name.parameterize
  end

  def to_param
    "#{id}/#{slug}"
  end
```

If I call `artist_path` with an artist object, this works as intended:

```
> app.artist_path(Artist.find 1234)
=> "/artists/1234/artist-name"
```

However, when I use call it with just the ID, it does not seem to use to_param at all:

```
> app.artist_path(id: 1234)
=> "/artists/1234"
```

tl;dr: **How can I force Rails to always instantiate the object and call `to_param` on it when `artist_path` is called, even when only the ID is specified?**

Comment: I just found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1209733), which acknowledges this behavior for route helpers, but only says (paraphrasing) "just don't call the helper only with the id".  Is this the solution?  I'd hope not, because I don't want the developer [to have to know of any limitation specific to this model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the reason why what you're asking won't work is because when you pass in values to the built-in/automatic URL helpers (like an ID, per your example), those values just get used to "fill in the blanks" in the route URL.

If you pass an array, the values from the array will get used in order until the URL is filled in.  If you pass a hash, those properties will get replaced into the URL.  An object, like your model, will use it's to_param method to fill in the values... etc.

I understand your concern regarding "having knowledge of the limitations of that model," however, this behavior is standard in Rails and I don't believe it would really throw anyone.  When you pass in an ID, as you do in your example, you're not telling the URL helper to "lookup a record via the model using this ID," you're simply telling it to "replace ':id' in the URL string with the ID you're providing."  I'm fairly certain the built-in URL helpers wouldn't even know how to lookup the record - what model to use, etc. - other than maybe inferring from the route/controller name.

My best suggestion is to always use the instantiated model/record.  If you were hoping the URL Helper would look that up for you, then there's no extra overhead as far as querying the database goes.  If there's some additional reason you want to avoid instantiating the record yourself, I'd be glad to hear it and possibly provide other suggestions.